# Guard installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, guard

i am install Guard on mac os x with guard-cucumber and have such errors in terminal:
http://pastebin.com/nsBJaWs2
What can be a problem? ( i am installing guard on jekyll source gem)

It looks, like there is a error of permission, but how to fix it?
Permission error appeared without guard-cucumber , i am only runned 
bundle exec guard init
bundle exec guard
and had the same errors , 
after that i installed cucumber , but the error is still exists (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove tmp dir , and guard cucumber works nice :)